# Merging the dataframe with different indices

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge

I have two data frames with data, now I want to merge the fields of the second data frame to first. If I call the index of the first data frame needs to get all the subject and topic names like below. Can anyone help me with this?

```
import pandas as pd
sub_data = {'Subjectid':['10','11'],'Author':['Author1','Author2'],'SubjectName':['Maths', 'English']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(sub_data)
print(df1)

topic_data = {'Topicid':['100','101','102'],'Subjectid':['10','10','11'],'TopicName':['Geometry','Trignometry', 'Tenses']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(topic_data)
print(df2)

subtopic_data = {'Subtopicid':['1000','1001','1002'],'Topicid':['100','101','102'],'Subjectid':['10','10','11'],'SubtopicTopicName':['Lines','Angles', 'PresentTenses']}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(subtopic_data)
print(df3)
```

Desired Output:

```
    Author    SubjectName   topicid   TopicName       Subopicid SubtopicName
10  Author1       Maths     100       Geometry        1000       Lines
10  Author1       Maths     100       Trignometry     1001      Angles
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with convert index to column by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and column to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df2.reset_index().set_index('Subjectid'), left_index=True, right_index=True)
print (df)
     Author SubjectName index    TopicName
10  Author1       Maths   100     Geometry
10  Author1       Maths   101  Trignometry
11  Author2     English   102       Tenses
```

Solution with changed data in question:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='Subjectid').set_index('Subjectid').rename_axis(None)
print (df)
     Author SubjectName Topicid    TopicName
10  Author1       Maths     100     Geometry
10  Author1       Maths     101  Trignometry
11  Author2     English     102       Tenses
```

For merge DataFrame `df3`:

```
df = (df1.merge(df2, on='Subjectid').set_index('Subjectid')
         .merge(df3, on=['Topicid','Subjectid']))
print (df)
    Author Subjectid SubjectName Topicid    TopicName Subtopicid  \
0  Author1        10       Maths     100     Geometry       1000   
1  Author1        10       Maths     101  Trignometry       1001   
2  Author2        11     English     102       Tenses       1002   

  SubtopicTopicName  
0             Lines  
1            Angles  
2     PresentTenses
```

Last for filtr only `Math` rows use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df4 = df[df['SubjectName'] == 'Maths']
print (df4)
    Author Subjectid SubjectName Topicid    TopicName Subtopicid  \
0  Author1        10       Maths     100     Geometry       1000   
1  Author1        10       Maths     101  Trignometry       1001   

  SubtopicTopicName  
0             Lines  
1            Angles
```

Comment: How do I call if I need only 10 index numbers I mean only maths subjects?

Comment: @lohithdevapatla - I see change data in question, you cannot do it, because then invalidate answers.

Comment: If i need only maths subject and related topic name, Isn't possible to do so?

Comment: @lohithdevapatla - yes, then use `out = df.loc[df['SubjectName'] == 'Maths', 'TopicName']`

Comment: @lohithdevapatla - or `out = df.loc[df['SubjectName'] == 'Maths', ['SubjectName','TopicName']]`

Comment: can you please add the above comment on your code and execute. Thanks

Comment: @lohithdevapatla - Done, added `df3` and filterd `Month`

Comment: Thank you so much. Ill reach you if i stuck anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use merge:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on ='Subjectid').set_index('Subjectid')

            Author  SubjectName Topicid TopicName
Subjectid               
10          Author1 Maths       100     Geometry
10          Author1 Maths       101     Trignometry
11          Author2 English     102     Tenses
```

Comment: How to combain if we have df3 also?

Comment: How do i call if i need only maths subjects related topics and subtopics(third one).I ll add soon

Comment: @lohithdevapatla - check my answer for merge multiple dataframes